# How to upload many files through javascript and keep UI responsive?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, performance, amazon-web-services

I have a website that needs to upload anywhere from 1-50 files to an Amazon Web Service Bucket. The way it is currently implemented is by looping through all the files and uploading them.  This appears to work because I can see the progress updates for the first ~6 upload and complete. As each one finishes, and connections become available, I see new ones start to upload.  The html page during this time is very unresponsive though.  Users cannot scroll the page.

Questions:
What is the best way to upload a list of files like this? Should they be queued somehow? or does the web browser handle the queue of files to upload already?

How do I keep the UI responsive while the uploads are in progress?

The below code is typed in manually, so please excuse any typos.

```
var files = []; //file is populated with up to ~50 files
files.forEach(function(file){

                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                        /* update ui to let user know upload for this file is complete */
                    }
                };

                xhr.upload.onprogress = function () { /* update ui progress indicator in grid for this file upload */ };
                xhr.open("PUT", "http://s3.amazonaws.com/" + AWS_Bucket_Name + "/" + File_Name, true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "AWS " + AWS_Access_Key + ":" + SignedRequest);
                xhr.setRequestHeader("x-amz-date", Current_Formatted_Date);
                xhr.send(this.file);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Well Well.

This is the issue which normally everyone faces.

We faced too, we were uploading about 4GB's of file to server, and it was freezing HTML browser.

So options is:
Create a HTTP File Handler in C# and AJAX to create a thread to upload file

Howerver in your case you are uploading it to Amazon, best is create a thread in background and free up browser

Comment: Do you mean using Web Workers  [link ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers) like the following? var myWorker = new Worker("my_task.js");

myWorker.addEventListener("message", function (oEvent) {
  console.log("Called back by the worker!\n");
}, false);

myWorker.postMessage(""); // start the worker.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, didn't realize I couldn't write code easily in comments.

Comment: Yes, why not! Also if your Code is in server scripting language like c# then you can use native code to create thread

Comment: I updated the code so it loops through each file selected to be uploaded by the user, and create a Web Worker for each that handles uploading the file to amazon s3. The web workers send back progress updates to the main thread which update the UI with the progress of each upload.  It works really well and keeps the UI responsive.  Thanks.